# Lenovo Energy Management on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Возможно ли установить Lenovo Energy Management на Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Смотрите на сайте Lenovo. Можно в wine но поведение может быть не предсказуемым. Вам хочется именно этот софт или какую-то проблему решить, ели проблему - опишите в вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

Насчет официальной поддержки от Lenovo не слышал (если только изощряться, ставя виндовый клиент). Альтернативой для Ubuntu может быть тула TLP. Позволяет манипулировать питанием отдельных компонентов машины. Подробнее [здесь](https://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html).

Comment: Тут, по моему, нету опции продуть пыль.... В основном для этого хотел  Lenovo Energy Management.....

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fan_speed_control - посмотрите здесь, тут есть решения для разгона вентилятора.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed - вот дубликат вопроса, тоже полезно